# Do the Klein bottle and torus topologies break the Lorentz invariance?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, symmetry, topology

According to [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01937), it seems that there are topologies (like the Klein bottle and the torus) that break some symmetries (like the Lorentz and translation invariances).

Is this right? Can they break more symmetries (like the Poincaré, diffeomorphism and CPT symmetries)?

Comment: The Lorentz invariance is a *local* symmetry, not a global one.  The topology can't break the local invariance.

Answer (score 5):

Without considering relativity, you have an analogous discussion in euclidean geometry. Take a flat torus $\mathbb T^2=\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$ whose universal cover space is the plane $\mathbb R^2$. While the torus is invariant by translation like the plane, it  does not have the full orthogonal group $O(2)$ as a symmetry group about any point. The lattice $\mathbb Z^2$ must be preserved for the map to be well defined on the torus, so the group of rotations is rather the [dihedral group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) $D_4$.

The same discussion applies for Minkowski metrics in relativity. For the (flat) Klein bottles, some translation symmetries also get lost. In general, since flat space is maximally symmetric with the full Poincaré group, as soon as you compactify it you will loose some symmetries.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on what you mean by "breaking" Lorentz invariance or the other symmetries. Remember that "symmetry" is not a property of just a geometry or topology or whatever, but of a *physical theory*: Symmetries are transformations that leave some relevant object in the *physical theory*, usually the action, invariant.

For instance, there are topologies (e.g. spheres in even dimensions, cf. [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/44861)) for which no Lorentz metric exists at all, i.e. which are not admissible as spacetimes. Does that mean they're "breaking Lorentz invariance"?

If we have a Lorentzian manifold $(M,g)$, then in order to say what "breaking" Lorentz invariance means, we first would have to say what it means for $M$ to *have* that symmetry. This is less straightforward than it may seem: We could say it's a local symmetry at every point, but locally at a point there are always normal coordinates such that $g$ is the Minkowski metric, and so at a point the symmetry group preserving the metric is always the full Lorentz group.

The paper you link means something different: It considers Lorentzian manifolds obtained as *quotients* $Q$ of Minkowski space $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ modulo some discrete group of transformations (or equivalently Lorentzian manifolds that are *covered* by Minkowski space) - the torus and the Klein bottle are particular quotients of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and so it makes sense to ask how the translations/rotations of $\mathbb{R}^2$ act on these quotients. Additionally they are considering the particular situation of (at least) two coupled fields, and they are interested in the effective action obtained after integrating out one of the fields. It turns out that not all the Lorentz/Poincaré symmetries of the theory of the two fields on the covering Minkowski space are symmetries of this resultant effective action, hence "broken".

Of course, this mechanism can in principle "break" any symmetry you want, there is no generic reason to expect an effective theory on some quotient spacetime to share the symmetries of the non-effective theory on its covering spacetime. Do note that this usage of "break" is different from the usage e.g. in "spontaneous symmetry breaking".